# Angular refresh ngFor with async observable after POST

Tags: angular, post, httpclient, ngfor, angular7

So I am displaying my images from HTTP GET like this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (currentGallery$ | async)?.imagesID" class="col-4">
     <img class="img-fluid" src="url/{{item}}/thumb">
</div>
```

but the problem occurs when it comes to upload image to the server and after that display the new image in gallery.

The only solution that I've got so far it is after upload POST, fire the new GET request, but this seems just bad.

```
this.http.post(url, formImageData).subscribe(data => {
    this.currentGallery$ = this.http.get<GalleryData>('url');
}
```

My post return the uploaded imageID, which I use to display images, so how can I after successful post request put it into array **'imagesID'** in my observable **currentGallery$**, so the ngFor can update itself without second GET after POST?

Or maybe there is some other more proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of another `component property` to store your `array` data instead of directly operating on an `Observable`, so that it will be easy to push newly generated `image id` in it.

pseudo code

```
public currentGallery = [];

ngOnInit(){
   // This should ideally happen from the service and map the data back to component
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => {
         this.currentGallery = data['imagesID'];
   });   
}
```

And once you receive the response from POST request you could directly push data (new id) to that array

```
this.http.post(url, formImageData).subscribe(data => {
    this.currentGallery.push(data.id)
}
```

And for loop will now iterate over an array as opposed to `Observable` array

```
<div *ngFor="let item of currentGallery" class="col-4">
     <img class="img-fluid" src="url/{{item}}/thumb">
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing it this way, but it is okay that I do not use async in ngFor? I have read some articles on the internet, that i should use async for http requests.

Comment: Yes, completely fine. `async` and `ngFor` need not be used together. `ngFor` can be used on any iterables, whereas `async` pipe is used against an observable. They are completely two different. If you are iterating over an `Observable` array directly, only then you use them together. `I have read some articles on the internet, that i should use async for http requests` - true, because http methods return an `Observable`.